# JavaScript code not changing style of dynamically generated html code

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase-realtime-database

So I've written javascript code to dynamically generate html code to display images on my website's page. In this dynamic code, I have given each image a button tag, so that when my user is logged in, it will display this button, (it is an x button so the user can delete it), and when I log out, I expect these buttons to leave, i.e. with an if-statement checking if there is an authenticated user present, display, and if not, set the display to none. However, my javascript to change the styling to none if there is no user, is not being applied. I have this same function working for two hard-coded buttons (the upload pic, and logout button, and they work fine). It simply does work on the dynamically generated code.

I've tried adding a default 'style='display:none;' within the dynamic html, and I've also tried putting that same style line within my css document, and neither are working. The display is set to none by default to begin with, and then after logging in, then changing the style to display:block.

Javascript to check for if a user is logged in, and then change the style accordingly:

```
const loggedIn = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-in');
const loggedInX = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-inX');

const setupUI = (user) => {
    if(user){
        //toggle UI elements
        loggedIn.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
        loggedInX.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');

    }
    else{
        loggedIn.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
        loggedInX.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');


    }
}
```

Javascript to load images from database and generate the code:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        var counter=0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var url = data.val().url;
            var dimensions = data.val().dimensions;
            var title = data.val().title;
            var year = data.val().year;
            var medium = data.val().year;

            content += '<div class="col-xl-4 col-xs-12 imageGrid">';
            content += '<a class="example-image-link" href="'+url+'" data-lightbox="example-1 '+counter+'"><img class="example-image" width="300" height="200" src="'+url+'" alt="image-1"/></a>';
            content += '<button class="imageButton logged-inX">x</button>';
            content += '</div>';
            counter++;
        });
        $('.displayImagesFromFirebase').append(content);
    }
});
```

So tl;dr, I want these buttons within the dynamically generated html code to display if there's a user, and not display if there isn't an authenticated user. This code works on hardcoded html within the page, but not the dynamically generated code from this function.

Comment: are you hitting breakpoint inside `snapshot.forEach`?

Comment: @naveen I am not. The code completely generates fine onto my page, if I inspect the page, all of the correct code is there. The images display perfectly, and the button is there. It's just that the javascript in my first snippet of code isn't having any effect on the style of the button tag. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call `setupUI` only when the page is first shown, that's the only time when it shows/hides elements. Any elements that are generated after that fact, are not affected by the code in `setupUI`.

The simplest solution is to move the `querySelectorAll` calls into `setupUI` and then re-execute `setupUI` when you modify the HTML:

```
const setupUI = (user) => {
    const loggedIn = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-in');
    const loggedInX = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-inX');

    if(user){
        //toggle UI elements
        loggedIn.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
        loggedInX.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');    
    }
    else{
        loggedIn.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
        loggedInX.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');    
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        var counter=0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var url = data.val().url;
            var dimensions = data.val().dimensions;
            var title = data.val().title;
            var year = data.val().year;
            var medium = data.val().year;

            content += '<div class="col-xl-4 col-xs-12 imageGrid">';
            content += '<a class="example-image-link" href="'+url+'" data-lightbox="example-1 '+counter+'"><img class="example-image" width="300" height="200" src="'+url+'" alt="image-1"/></a>';
            content += '<button class="imageButton logged-inX">x</button>';
            content += '</div>';
            counter++;
        });
        $('.displayImagesFromFirebase').append(content);
        setupUI(firebase.auth().currentUser);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the exact solution, the page loads perfectly and functions as it needs to. Thank you for your solution!